# Open cv2 error 1287 reading and writing a video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having the error here,

```
dif = cv2.absdiff(frameAnterior, frameAtual)
```

The error only happens in the last frame of the video.

Error:

> cv2.error: ......\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1287: error: (-209)
>   The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same
>   size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor
>   'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I editted it , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error has to do with the last frame of the video ending. Maybe you should try to stop reading before the last frame? With a break.